# "Unable to re-open an already closed object", when reading data from sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my android app,i m using sqlite database but when using a query to read data from SQLite its giving me error. This is my code for creating table.

```
package com.example.mydb;
public class Dbadapter {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;

private static final String DATABASE_TABLE18 = "modalation_medicine_table";
private static final String MOD_ID = "modalation_previousss_id";
private static final String MOD_MED_ID = "modalation_medicine_id";
private static final String MOD_MEDICINE = "modalation_medicine";

private static final String CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE18 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
        + DATABASE_TABLE18
        + " ("
        + MOD_MED_ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + MOD_MEDICINE
        + " text, "
        + MOD_ID
        + " integer, "
        + " FOREIGN KEY ("
        + MOD_ID
        + ") REFERENCES "
        + DATABASE_TABLE5
        + " ("
        + MODALATION_KEY_ID
        + "));";

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
          db.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE18);

    ContentValues modalation_medicine = new ContentValues();
        modalation_medicine.put(MOD_MEDICINE, "Natrum Muriaticum");
        modalation_medicine.put(MOD_ID, 1);
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE18, null, modalation_medicine);

        modalation_medicine.put(MOD_MEDICINE, "Calcarea Carbonica");
        modalation_medicine.put(MOD_ID, 1);
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE18, null, modalation_medicine);

        modalation_medicine.put(MOD_MEDICINE, "Phosphorus");
        modalation_medicine.put(MOD_ID, 1);
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE18, null, modalation_medicine);
}

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + DATABASE_TABLE18);

    }

}

public Dbadapter(Context c) {
    ourContext = c;
}

public Dbadapter open() throws SQLException{
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    ourHelper.close();
}
```

Now, when m using this method to read data from my sqLite db, it gives me an error "Unable to re-open an already closed object".

```
public boolean mod_app_symps(String l, String modfinalMed) {
        String[] modalation = new String[] { MOD_ID, MOD_MEDICINE };
        Cursor c24;
        boolean iscontain = false;
        c24 = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE18, modalation, "modalation_previousss_id = ? AND modalation_medicine = ?",new String[] { l , modfinalMed } , null, null, null);
        if(c24.getCount() > 0) {
            iscontain = true;
        }
        return iscontain;
    }
```

I tried to solve the problem through google but nothing helped!
P.S : I have many other methods that are doing the same work i.e read data from SQLite db, and they all work fine. The error is coming only on this method.

Edit: this method works fine

```
public String[] getmodMed(long l) {
        String[] modalation_med = new String[] { MOD_ID, MOD_MEDICINE};
        Cursor c19 = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE18, modalation_med, MOD_ID + "='" + l + "'" , null, null, null, null);
        String mod_medicine[]= new String[c19.getCount()];
        int imodmedicine = c19.getColumnIndex(MOD_MEDICINE);
        if(c19 != null){
            c19.moveToFirst();
            while(!c19.isAfterLast()) {
                for(int i =0; i< c19.getCount(); i++) { 
                mod_medicine[i]= c19.getString(imodmedicine);
                c19.moveToNext();
                } }
        }
        return mod_medicine;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because of this line of code:

```
public void close() {
ourHelper.close();
}
```

You close a database and then want to access it again.

Comment: If this is the problem then the other methods that m using to read data from same db must not work. right?

Comment: Well, the problem will occur if you close the database with this method and then try to access it with any other method.

Try commenting ourHelper.close(); and see what happens

Comment: Sure! :) but i have added the method the method in my question that works fine even with the line OurHelper.close, Can u tell me the reason why?

Comment: But I don't see that you ever called close() in the getmodMed() method :)

Answer (score 0):

We need to see more code, specifically "ourDatabase". It sounds like it's getting closed somewhere before you run that method. Try adding SQLiteDatabase db = ourHelper.getWriteableDatabase right before you query, then run the query against "db"

```
public boolean mod_app_symps(String l, String modfinalMed) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = outHelper.getWriteableDatabase();
    String[] modalation = new String[] { MOD_ID, MOD_MEDICINE };
    Cursor c24;
    boolean iscontain = false;
    c24 = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE18, modalation, "modalation_previousss_id = ? AND modalation_medicine = ?",new String[] { l , modfinalMed } , null, null, null);
    if(c24.getCount() > 0) {
        iscontain = true;
    }         
    return iscontain;
}
```